# Как будет деструктуризация на ts?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
let { email, password } = require("./credentials.json");
```

Comment: деструктуризация сработает, а вот TS нет смысла впрягать, так как вряд ли он сможет заглянуть в файл, это уже время исполнения кода, т.е. когда он будет приведен к JS

Comment: @DaniilLoban а ему и не надо заглядывать. Это явно из какого-то API с заранее известным интерфейсом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для любой внешней функции, возвращающей `any | unknown | черти_что`, при условии что тип известен, можно либо самостоятельно описать интерфейс, либо скопировать его у предоставленного API(вполне вероятно что он имеется). И явно привести результат к интерфейсу.

```
interface ICredentials {
  email: string
  password: string
  // ...
}

let { email, password } = require("./credentials.json") as ICredentials; // или так - as unknown as ICredentials
// email is string
// password is string
```

TypeScript Lang [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQEkDCMoBMqQgIA2AzqgN7CqpQC2CIxAXKqRDOAObWoAOCUqQDuAexi5W7TmB40A9PNQA6VcAC+wYPiTEEOVHACuYJBBCiwqHAEcjIHAAoBEABZSO3AJSsEYAJ4A3FrEUBCUtAxMADT8giLiuKjqqAC81lB2DlCOAETK8kg4+IQkpMoAVqSWuV6oghjYeATmZYGoiqiAHCCA3CBdqIBCIIAMIIBcIKgAtPXkJgDWYKLCVg1YxS1EZMCd9IzEqCDk0tybSgJCYhJ7B56ywEA)